# Basic list operations optimization in Haskell

Tags: optimization, haskell

Does some basic list operation in Haskell(e.g. ghc) are optimized equivalently to their imperative counterparts?

For example if I have some finite but computed in runtime list does its length is attached to this list or evaluating function (length xs) have to traverse whole list recursively?

Is there some list of common Haskell(ghci or in general) optimization made by compiler?

Comment: It is very uncommon for functional languages like Haskell to cache the length of a list, so you can only find it by counting through the list (in fact I don't know any that do - maybe Clojure as it uses a novel list representation?). If you use the common list representation of a sum type with Nil and Cons cases - you would have to put a cached length at every Cons constructor. Then you immediately have maintenance problems for the cache length after common operations that change the list length like filter or concat.

Comment: Note that some data structures in Haskell's standard library do cache the length - e.g. Data.Set, but these are opaque structures - you can't pattern match on a Set like you can a List.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is very good at doing optimizations on lists, but not the type you describe.  Haskell doesn't have "special" handling for lists -- they're like other normal Haskell types, albeit with some built-in syntactic sugar.  It's nothing more special than

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

would be.

Haskell optimizes lists using what's called foldr/build fusion, which e.g. optimizes `map f (filter p list)` so that it doesn't produce an intermediate list for the `filter`, but does both the map and the filter in the same traversal.  See [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html#id644345) for details on what "fuses," or read [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion#foldr.2Fbuild_4) for more details on how it works.

Additionally, Haskell's more modern array libraries use a more aggressive type of fusion that can e.g. fuse `sum (map f (enumFromN 0 n))` to a tail-recursive iteration from `0` to `n-1`, which is basically exactly what you want.  Investigate the [vector package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector), [this blog post](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/) for what stream fusion can do, and [this paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.104.7401) for details.

Comment: Rewrite rules look very interesting. Could you provide some more answers on how they work? Lets for example analize rule map f (map g l) = map (f.g) l. Is left side of equation sign slow part and right part fast part and compiler alway applies this rule or maybe compiler decides by itself whether rewriting would improve code? Could you provide some more materials?

Comment: The compiler applies it always whenever the compiler's optimization level is set to at least `-O`.  More details on the rewrite rules are [here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, Haskell doesn't do that. If you compute the following code:

```
let x = [1..5]
let y = [1..1000000]
```

It's going to take the compiler longer to find the length of `y` than `x`, because there are more values in `y` and the compiler has to count ever one to find the length of the list.